# Maximum table size in YugabyteDB?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is there a maximum table size in YugabyteDB like in PostgreSQL ?

The table size is in PostgreSQL is limited by the maximum number of blocks in a table, which is 2^32 blocks. PostgreSQL has a configurable block size which allows up to 32768 bytes per block, which would give a maximum table size of 128TB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't.

The lower half of YugabyteDB (storage/transaction/distribution/etc. layers - which we refer to as DocDB) is a ground up implementation that doesn't reuse Postgres' lower half.

DocDB is elastic and scales to multiple nodes. You are basically limited by the aggregate storage capacity across the nodes in the cluster at any given time. But you can add more nodes to get more capacity.. and data will get redistributed/rebalanced automatically.

See more info in [Architecture section](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/) in docs.